# How to retrieve ONLY pivot rows with Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot, relationship

I've got three models and relative tables:

- appointments (model: Appointment)
- therapies (model: Therapy)
- appointment_therapies (no model)

Every appointment may have a lot of therapies (massage, first visit, running, etc.).

Thru a search form, I need to retrieve - for example - all the massage therapies done in all the appointments, that is I need the loop thru the appointment_therapies table.

I tried:

```
Appointment::with(['therapies' => function ($sub) use ($request) {
   $sub->where('therapy_id', $request->therapy_id);
}]) ->get();
```

With this query I get all the appointments AND all the therapies as children.

- appointment 1

  - therapy 1
  - therapy 2
- appointment 2

  - therapy 3
  - therapy 4

As a result I cannot loop thru the therapies; what I wish is like:

- therapy 1
- therapy 2
- therapy 3
- therapy 4

---

I have edited whereHas to with, which is more correct.

Comment: "*I have edited whereHas to with, which is more correct.*" - It's really not... I deleted my previous comment, see the comments below, but with your `with()` logic, you'll receive x `Appointment` records, each with a `Collection` of exactly 1 or 0 `Therapy` records, but if it's 1, **it'll be the same `Therapy` record repeated for every `Appointment`**.

Comment: If you use `whereHas()`, as the answer below suggests, you'll get x `Appointment` records, with 0 or x `Therapy` records, as long as the `Appointment` is related to the `Therapy` that matches `$request->therapy_id`. You can use `whereHas()` in conjunction with `with()`, but you'd want to use `whereHas('therapies', function(){ ... })->with(['therapies'])->get();` (i.e. don't add any additional logic to the `with()` clause.

Comment: The point is that whereHas() returns all the therapies when the where clause is true, also those whose therapy_id are not the requested one. Instead I need to retrieve only the therapies which have the requested therapy_id.

Comment: Is `therapies.therapy_id` not unique? Do you have 2 columns, `therapies.id` and `therapies.therapy_id`? I think you might need to post your models and migrations; too many unknowns here...

Comment: I need to retreive appointment_therapy rows, which has id, appointment_id and therapy_id.

Comment: Pivot tables don't generally have an `id`, and targeting `appointment_therapy.therapy_id` is the same as targeting `therapies.id`. I think you're misunderstanding how a `many-to-many` (`belongsToMany()`) is queried.

Comment: @TimLewis If an appointment has many therapies of the same type, I must have the id column.

Answer (score 1):

The pluck method can return the therapies, and you should also eager load the therapies to avoid running duplicate queries.

```
$appointments = Appointment::whereHas('therapies', function ($sub) use ($request) {
   $sub->where('therapy_id', $request->therapy_id);
})->with('therapies')->get();

$therapies = $appointments->pluck('therapy');
```

The therapies variable will be a collection of all the therapies attached to the appointments returned by the first query.

If you need the returned collection to still have the appointment information, base your query on the therapies instead and eager load the related appointments

```
Therapy::where('id', $request->therapy_id)->with('appointments');
```

Comment: therapy or therapies should work, whereHas() requires the model name to be plural if it's many to many but pluck will take either the name of the model (Therapy) or the name of the returned collection attribute (therapies). 

As for the second part, with a many to many relationship the whereHas closure will take either the name of the column on the pivot table (therapy_id) or a non-ambiguous column name (therapy.id) but if you're querying from the therapy side therapy_id is meaningless

Comment: I misunderstood the second point, fixed that. But I maintain the first is correct, I tested this code in tinker with my own models that have a many to many relationship. In fact if I pluck('roles') instead it returns a collection of collections, which is not what the question asker wants and would just leave them in the same position as far as looping through them goes. ->pluck('role') returns a collection of just the models, not a nested collection.

Comment: Weird, but I suppose that yes, the point about nested collections makes sense. I'll have to do some more experimenting, but if you say that works, then leave it as is. There's still the overarching problem that this whole issue doesn't exactly make sense (as you _should_ only get a single `Therapy` with this logic), but I guess that's beside the point.

Comment: The query OP is running gets all appointments that have that therapy included, it's a whereHas() not a with() so technically they're not even loading the therapies to begin with. The appointments can still have other therapies and $appointment->therapies would still return ALL the therapies attached to that appointment.

Comment: Good point. I don't think I've personally had a use case where I wanted to use `whereHas()` without the corresponding `with()` clause, but you are correct.

Comment: I removed whereHas() and added with(), which is more correct as you said, but the problem still remains. Thank you

Comment: @Drew it's not an either or, you should use the whereHas to filter your records and the with() to eager load them. If only do the former then running the ->pluck() method will run a separate query for each appointment, but it will give you the collection you want in the end. If you only use ->with() than it will only return the therapies that match therapy ID and they will still be in a sub collection like your original problem. I'll update my answer to show how to get the result you want without duplicate queries.